How to edit a variable inside of a ForEach loop
I have this code here:
struct CheckoutView: View {

    var itemInfoList: [itemInfo]
    @State private var mutableItemInfoList: [itemInfo] = []
    
    init(itemInfoList: [itemInfo]) {
        self.itemInfoList = itemInfoList
        self.mutableItemInfoList = itemInfoList
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(itemInfoList, id: \.self) { newItem in
       
            Button(action: {
                newItem.size = selectedSizesString
                // problematic line
            }) {
                Text("Print Selected Sizes")
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Selected Sizes"),
                    message: Text(selectedSizesString),
                    dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct itemInfo: Hashable {
    var item: Item
    var size: String
    var comment: String
}

I am trying to edit the size property inside of each item, but I am getting this error:  > Cannot assign to property: 'newItem' is a 'let' constant
I am not sure what I am doing wrong, my best guess would be that item is inside a ForEach loop.

You need a Binding, you should work through Apple’s tutorials. Watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Your code is incomplete, It is difficult to answer with code but can try to solve your problem by getting the index of "newItem"  inside ForEach and then updating the value at a specific index  in itemInfoList and also make the itemInfoList as @State var

Like this:
ForEach($items) { $item in

